# Deterministic finite machine recognizing language $((00)^*|1(11)^*)^*$

Tags: solution-verification, formal-languages, finite-state-machine

Is the following deterministic finite machine correct for recognizing the language $((00)^*|1(11)^*)^*$?

Let $M=(Q,\Sigma,\delta,q_0,F)$ where $Q = \{q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4,q_5,q_\Delta\}$ is the set of states, $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ is the alphabet, $\delta:Q\times\Sigma\to Q$ is the transition function given by
$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
q\overset{\LARGE\setminus}{\phantom{.}}\overset{\Large i}{\phantom{l}}&0&1\\\hline
q_0&q_1&q_2\\
q_1&q_3&q_\Delta\\
q_2&q_\Delta&q_4 \\
q_3&q_1&q_\Delta\\
q_4&q_\Delta&q_5\\
q_5&q_\Delta&q_4 \\
q_\Delta&q_\Delta&q_\Delta
\end{array},
$$
$q_0$ is the start state, and $F=\{q_0,q_2,q_3,q_5\}$ is the set of accept states. Then $M$ recognizes the language described by the regular expression $((00)^*|1(11)^*)^*$.

Visualization:

[image: finite machine]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your language is equivalent to $(00|1)^*$. It's much clearer now that our machine should only reject sequences that contain an odd number of zeroes consecutively. From this, we can define a simpler machine

Let $ M = (Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_0, F) $ where $Q = \{q^0, q^1, q^\Delta\}$ is the set of states, $\Sigma = \{0, 1\}$ is the alphabet, $ \delta : Q \times \Sigma \to Q $ is the transition function defined by

$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
q\overset{\LARGE\setminus}{\phantom{.}}\overset{\Large i}{\phantom{l}}&0&1\\
\hline
q^0&q^1&q^0\\
q^1&q^0&q^\Delta\\
q^\Delta&q^\Delta&q^\Delta \\
\end{array},
$$

$q_0 = q^0$ is the start state, and $F = \{q_0\}$ is the set of accept states.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite.

If we consider that the string $1111$ is part the language described by $((00)^{*}|1(11)^{*})^{*}$, but the machine when given the input $1111$ ends in state $q_{4}$ (which is not an accepting state).

Comment: So I guess we could remove state $q_4$ and $q_5$ and we would get the following: https://imgur.com/5mLGVIC. Right?

Comment: @NimaKimi Yes exactly, as long as when we delete $q_{4}$ and $q_{5}$ we make sure that in our visualisation we make an arrow going from $q_{2}$ to itself, labeled '$1$'.

Comment: Got it, thanks.